# Interpretation of mutual information

Tags: information-theory

I remember having read the following interpretation of Shannon's information somewhere

"*For discrete variables, I(X;Y) quantifies how well we can discriminate among the outcomes of Y by looking at the outcomes of X (and viceversa)*"

This interpretation is fundamental for my paper cause it stresses the "discrimination" aspect. However, I cannot find a reference for it anymore.

So I am wondering whether:

- whether this is a well-accepted interpretation of MI and
- whether anyone could point out a reference for it.

**Addendum:** I think that the property that MI is zero if either one of the variables has only one single outcome is actually a fundamental property of MI. In particular it speaks against some common interpretations of MI, for example:

- MI quantifies the predictability of $Y$ from $X$ (or viceversa): wouldn't $I(X;Y)$ then be maximal and not minimal when either $Y$ has only one outcome, since it is perfectly predictable?
- MI quantifies the statistical relationship between $X$ and $Y$. But then I would expect $I(X;Y)$ to be maximal when both $X$ and $Y$ have only one possible outcome, since in this case the statistical relationship is deterministically defined.

I am looking for an interpretation that stresses the fact that for MI to make sense both $X$ and $Y$ must have at least two outcomes each.

Comment: Can you define what it means to 'discriminate among the outcomes of Y'?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have learned while studying information theory, but I do not know a reference for a quote stressing the discrimination aspect.

I think of mutual information as measuring the size of the intersection in the Venn diagram between the information "contained" in two sources (random variables). If that is a complete overlap, then the outcome of $X$ will exactly be the outcome of $Y$. If there is no overlap, then the outcome of $X$ will not say anything about the outcome of $Y$. If there is partial overlap, the outcome of $X$ should sway your belief in some direction about the outcome of $Y$ (helping to discriminate between which outcomes are likely/unlikely) but will not guarantee the outcome of $Y$.

Comment: The point I want to make is that MI is intrinsically a non point-wise quantity. Indeed, if X or Y have only one possible outcome then MI is zero. This conflicts with the interpretation of MI in terms of "predictability", since if that interpretation were to hold you would expect MI to be maximal and not minimal if Y has only one outcome. Instead, discrimination can only be done between at least two items.

Comment: I suppose in the case of both $X$ and $Y$ having only one outcome, there is no information or "surprisal" contained in observing either outcome, i.e., the area of the circles in the Venn diagram would be $0$, and so whether you consider maximal or minimal overlap, the area of that overlap is still $0$. Have you ever heard of thinking of entropy and mutual information in terms of "surprisal"? This is a nice analogy.

Comment: I think surprisal goes well with your idea of discrimination, because there needs to be possible uncertainty (i.e. at least two items) to be surprised, or to talk about discriminating between them.

Comment: Yes. I know the surprisal interpretation. Surprisal is well defined for variable with only one possible outcome and is equal to zero. Also, for MI to be zero it is enough that either X or Y are singleton.